# attempting to change height and width of canvas for chart

Tags: javascript, html, css, chart.js

I am not able to change the height and width of my canvas. It seems somehow the javascript rendering of my chart is overwriting.

Here is my HTML CODE

```
<body>
    <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
</body>
```

JS CODE

```
var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [
        {
          label: '# of Votes',
          data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderWidth: 1,
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 0, 15, 0.54)'
        },  
            {
                label: '# of Points',
                data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
                borderWidth: 1
            }
        ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
                    reverse: false
        }
      }]
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

CSS CODE

```
canvas { background-color : #eee;
width: 100 !important;
height: 100 !important;
}
```

Here is my [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9twzxusc/) and as you can see i am even trying to overwrite the height and width via css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSS has no units. Use `100px !important;` or `100% !important;` etc.